# MySQL Split values into rows. Error in creating function

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to seperate delimited string in a column into rows.
For example

```
ID Value           ID Value  
---------          ----------  
1  a,b     into    1  a  
2  c,d             1  b  
                   2  c  
                   2  d
```

I've tried these solution

1.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep VARCHAR(32), @s VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT r.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as Item
        FROM (SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,'& ','&amp; '),'<','&lt;'), @sep, '</r><r>') + '</r></root>') as valxml) x
        CROSS APPLY x.valxml.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
    )
```

ERROR:
1. syntax error at [ from [dbo] in the first line.
2. sometimes an error is at RETURNS instead.

2.

```
SELECT T1.reference, T1.name, T2.my_Splits AS subjects, T1.subtitile
FROM
 (
  SELECT *,
  CAST('<X>'+replace(T.subjects,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
  FROM archive T
 ) T1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as my_Splits
 FROM T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
 ) T2
```

ERROR:
1. syntax error at XML from AS XML in CAST line.
2. syntax error at CROSS APPLY. It says JOIN is missing.

3.

```
SELECT A.[State],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [State],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([City], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TableA) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

ERROR:
syntax error at ( from Split.a.value(....

I'm very new to SQL and couldn't fully understand these solutions given on the internet. It seems to work fine for everyone else but I don't know why I keep getting these syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure you use MySQL? And it's a bad idea to store data in that way you do, as you already have noticed it causes a lot or problems...

Comment: @jarlh I'm pretty sure what I'm using is MySQL and the data is given as an assignment so I couldn't do much about that...

Comment: @miles Are you positive you are using MySQL?  That syntax above is a SQL Server syntax which would be why it is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Its really a bad way to store data as `CSV` in a single column. Consider changing you table design

```
SELECT id,
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Value
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               Cast ('<M>' + Replace(Value, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   archive) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a5f7/1)

If you need a function then use this.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep VARCHAR(32),
                              @s   VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Value
       FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@sep, @s, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
              CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) 


SELECT id,
       cs.value
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply [dbo].[Split] (Value, ',') cs
```

Comment: I still get an error at the first square bracket [ from [dbo].[Split]  What if instead of comma, data is stored as 'a and b', is there a simpler solution for that?  Thanks a lot

Comment: They've tagged this with MySQL, this syntax won't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This works only if there is one character on each side of the delimiter:

```
select id, left(value,1) as value from db union select id, right(value,1) from db order by id, value asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the count of splitted values fix you can use follow code, example three parts

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',1) AS value FROM tablename
  UNION
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',2),',',-1) FROM tablename
  UNION
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',3),',',-1) FROM tablename
) result
ORDER BY id
```

give follow result

```
id | value                   id | value
---+---------                ---+------
1  | 1,aa,xxx                1  | 1
2  | 2,yyy        into       1  | aa
3  | zzz,3,cc                1  | xxx
                             2  | 2
                             2  | yyy
                             3  | zzz
                             3  | 3
                             3  | cc
```